# Why is there a mixed content error when all content is https?

Tags: html, iframe, https, mixed-content

I am attempting to use an iframe to load content from another one of my sites, but get a mixed content error in chrome. Both `//` and `https://` yield the same error.

Iframe:

```
<iframe src='https://ajg0702.us/bans' id='frame' frameBorder="0" onload='checkFrame()'>Please update your browser.</iframe>
```

The function

```
function checkFrame() {
  var f = document.getElementById('frame');
  if(f.src != "//ajg0702.us/bans" & f.src != "https://ajg0702.us/bans" & f.src != "http://astrophoenix.com/~aiden/bans") {
    console.log("Fallback webpage! current: " + f.src)
    //Will load backup page if main page gets redirected somewhere else
    f.src = "http://mc.skylinemc.us/~aiden/bans"
  }
}
```

I also tested a plain iframe with only the src tag, and the problem persisted.

Googling my issue has only lead to normal mixed content errors (attempting to use http on https page)

Additional note: I am using Cloudflare on both sites. I attempted to search my problem with Cloudflare in the query, but only found similar results (to when I googled the problem without Cloudflare)

Comment: Please show your JavaScript, it might contain some hints.

Comment: Sure, edited to include the function. The javascript part I wrote mostly for me, because my school decided to block ajg0702.us for some reason. I removed the javascript, and it still had the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix!

Turns out I needed to add `index.php` to the end of the url.

Answer (score 0):

In `CheckFrame`() you set the source to:

```
f.src = "http://mc.skylinemc.us/~aiden/bans"
```

That is NOT `https` and explains why you get the error. Simply change the

```
src
```

to start with

```
https://
```

Comment: That code is only run if the iframe is redirected somewhere other than https://ajg0702.us/bans. I know this code is not run, because the console.log above it does not show up in console